# Integrate Dailymotion Analytics api

Tags: analytics, dailymotion-api

Is there any api for getting the analytics detail of dailymotion channel. I want to integrate the analytics on my website.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

It is right, your question is not very self-explanatory... 
I guess you want any insight on views and revenues through the API ?

For views, we have several `views_last_*` and a `views_total` fields (see https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#video-views_last_day-field).

About revenues, we do not have it so far, stay tuned !